# Simple starter angular2 app yields: "Exception: No Directive annotation found on AppComponent"

Tags: angularjs, angular, visual-studio-2015

Trying to execute a very simple Angular 2 application based on Angular's "5 MIN QUICKSTART" always fails with the following error message being displayed in the console window of the Chrome browser: "Exception: No Directive annotation found on AppComponent".  The application differs from Angular's "5 MIN QUICKSTART" in that node.js is not being used.  Rather Visual Studio 2015 was used to write and execute the application.  NPM was used to download the "node_modules" and "typings" directories and their contents.  The "5 MIN QUICKSTART" code then was modified to accommodate what was downloaded using NPM.  Basically that amounted to replacing "@angular/core" with "node_modules/@angular/core/index".  A single file in "node_modules" was modified in this fashion.  These modifications appeared to work.  All the angular modules and application modules were successfully loaded.  However once that completes the application fails.

The application is very simple.  Everything downloaded from Angular is where it is suppose to be.  The application appears to get very close to successfully loading and executing...but fails at the last second.  Can anyone provide some guidance on how to make this app run?

Following are the relevant code files.

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>

    <script>
        System.paths = {
            "Components/App.Component": "Components/App.Component.js"
        }
    </script>

    <script>
        System.import('main.js').catch(
            function (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        );
    </script>

</head>

<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>
    <app-view>Loading...</app-view>
</body>

</html>
```

**Main.ts**

```
import {bootstrap} from 'node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index';
import {AppComponent} from 'Components/App.Component';

bootstrap(AppComponent).catch(err => alert(err)).then(compRef => {
});
```

**App.Component.ts**

```
    import {Component} from 'node_modules/@angular/core/index';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-view',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent
{
}
```

Using "import {Component} from '@angular/core'" is what the folks at Angular specify should be used (in the "5 MIN QUICKSTART").  But the QUICKSTART assumes the app will be compiled using the specified Typescript compiler and executed using Node.js.  "import {Component} from '@angular/core'" works because of how SystemJS, the module loader, is configured in systemjs.config.js.  When developing with Visual Studio 2015 (VS) a Typescript compiler specific to VS is used and a server specific to VS is used to execute the application.  Using "import {Component} from '@angular/core'" inside VS leads to Intellisense (code completion) and compiler errors because '@angular/core' implies a file whose name is "core" (plus an extension) and which can be found in a directory called "@angular" which is a sub-directory of the application directory.  Of course there is no such directory or file.  The actual file(s) can be found at "~/node_modules/@angular/core/index.d.ts" when Intellisence is operating and at "~/node_modules/@angular/core/index.js" when the compiler is executing (I think).  So when using VS "node_modules/@angular/core/index" has to be used because it refers to the exact location of the desired file.  But using that path leads to the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should import the `Component` decorator this way:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: '@angular/core' does not work when using Visual Studio 2015.  See addition to original issue above.